# Notice: Use of undefined constant tournamentid - assumed 'tournamentid' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cricket Score Board\displayresults.php on line 47

Tags: php

i am getting an error in php Notice: Use of undefined constant tournamentid - assumed 'tournamentid' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cricket Score Board\displayresults.php on line 47

```
<?php
    $sqlteams = "SELECT * FROM tournaments where status='Active'";
    $sqlquery  = mysqli_query($cnn,$sqlteams);
    while($rsres = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlquery))
    {

(line 47)   if($rsres["tournamentid"]== $_GET["tournamentid"])
        {
        echo "<option value='$rsres[tournamentid]' selected>$rsres[name]</option>";
        }
        else
        {
        echo "<option value='$rsres[tournamentid]'>$rsres[name]</option>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: are you getting `tournamentid` from request ?

Comment: Looks like you have a <select name='tournamentid'> somewhere. show at least the code with the corresponding form.

Comment: '".   ."   ws the culprit...  thanks for ur effort :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add ' ' in your $rsres['tournamentid'] and $rsres['name'] variables.
Change those lines :

```
        if($rsres["tournamentid"]== $_GET["tournamentid"])
        {
        echo "<option value='".$rsres['tournamentid']."' selected>".$rsres['name']."</option>";
        }
        else
        {
        echo "<option value='".$rsres['tournamentid']."'>".$rsres['name']."</option>";
        }
```